# Is there an easy way to calculate this modulo expression?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

$$3 ^ {3^{1000000000}} \bmod 1000000007$$

Also, is there a way to convert $a^{b^ c}$ to a form $d ^ e$ where $a \ne d$ and $e \ne b ^ c$?

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem?  Do you know [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)?  They are what you use.  You could search the site for references to those and find many problems of this type.

Comment: @RossMillikan I didn't know! Thanks, I'll take a look at them.

Comment: According to online calculators, $1000000007 = 10^9+7$ is prime, $1000000006 = 10^9+6 = 2 \times 500000003$ and $500000003$ is prime.

Comment: @peterwhy I apologise. I really don't understand the implications of that... Does this have something to do with Euler's theorem?

Comment: You will when you read about the theorems I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Fermat's little theorem, the problem boils down to computing
$$ 3^{10^9}\pmod{500000003}. $$
That can be done by repeating $a\mapsto a^{10}\pmod{500000003}$ a few times. We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} 3^{10}&\equiv& 59049\pmod{500000003} \\ 
3^{10^2}&\equiv& 295914588\pmod{500000003} \\
3^{10^3}&\equiv& 172803091\pmod{500000003} \\
&\ldots& \\
3^{10^8}&\equiv& 299145277\pmod{500000003} \\
3^{10^9}&\equiv& 283950619\pmod{500000003}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence $3^{10^9}\equiv 283950619\pmod{1000000006}$ and
$$ 3^{10^9}\equiv 3^{283950619} \equiv \color{red}{930782551}\pmod{1000000007} $$

This is clearly computer-assisted, since no one in his right mind would perform this amount (of simple, but lengthy) computations by hand.

Comment: @Coldspeed: I bet this Wikipedia page will be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Note for readers, the deduction from $$3^{10^9} \equiv 283950619 \pmod{500000003}$$ to $$3^{10^9} \equiv 283950619 \pmod{1000000006}$$ is not automatic; this requires knowing that
$$3^{10^9} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}.$$

Comment: @peterwhy: of course, but it shouldn't be difficult to notice that any power of $3$ is odd.